# Plugin admin page meta_box toggle and order state not saving

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, metabox

I can't get the toggle state and open/close status of meta_boxes on my plugin admin page to be stored. The ajax response is always 0

I'm using meta boxes to hold sections of menu for a plugin.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'common' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-lists' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'postbox' );
```

are called on an init add_action hook

add_meta_boxes are called with admin_menu add_action hook
Then the admin page for my plugin is rendered thus...

```
<div class="wrap" id="church-admin">
<div id="icon-index" class="icon32"><br/></div><h2>Church Admin Plugin</h2>
<div id="poststuff">
    <!-- #post-body .metabox-holder goes here -->
    <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-2">
        <!-- meta box containers here -->
        <form style="display:none" method="get" action="">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('closedpostboxes', 'closedpostboxesnonce', false ); ?>
            <?php wp_nonce_field('meta-box-order', 'meta-box-order-nonce', false ); ?>
        </form>
        <?php do_meta_boxes('church-admin','advanced',null);?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){$(".if-js-closed").removeClass("if-js-closed").addClass("closed");
            postboxes.add_postbox_toggles( pagenow );
            });
</script>
```

Why are opn/close toggles and order changes not saved?

Comment: Why are your meta-boxes outside the form?

Comment: No good reason! Removed style="display:none" from form tag and closed the form tag after do_meta_boxes. Can still toggle and close, but it's not saved! BTW the scripts are in the footer for some unknown reason!

Comment: Try adding `wp_enqueue_script( 'post' );`, and are you sure your scripts are enqueueing correctly?

Comment: Yes - toggles and order change still work, but aren't remembered on page refresh still

Comment: Can't answer my own question - but changing the jquery did the trick. postboxes.add_postbox_toggles( 'church-admin'); church-admin is the name of my plugin. That made it work.

Comment: You can answer your question in about 12 hours I think. Please do so when you can. It keeps the site neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the save to work the `postboxes.add_postbox_toggles( pagenow );` needs to be replaced with

```
postboxes.add_postbox_toggles( 'pluginname' );
```

In my case `postboxes.add_postbox_toggles( 'church-admin' );`

I've blogged a how to [using meta boxes on plugin admin pages](http://www.themoyles.co.uk/2013/03/using-meta-boxes-on-plugin-admin-pages/)